# Request para a Cielo com node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Esta dando o seguinte código de erro:

```
TypeError: First argument must be a string or Buffer
```

Meu código esta assim:

```
        request: function (dataJson, callback) {

        var options = {
            hostname: 'apisandbox.cieloecommerce.cielo.com.br',
            port: 443,
            secureProtocol: 'TLSv1_method',
            encoding: 'utf-8',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Accept-Charset': 'utf-8',
                'Content-Length': 0
            },
            method: 'POST'
        };

        if (ambienteDeProducao || false) {
            options.hostname = 'api.cieloecommerce.cielo.com.br';
        }

        var postData = dataJson;
        options.headers['Content-Length'] = Buffer.byteLength(postData);
        var req = https.request(options, function (res) {
            var data = [];
            res.on('data', function (chunk) {
                data.push(chunk);
            });
            res.on('end', function () {
                callback(null, data.join(''))
            });
        });
        req.write(postData);
        req.end();
    }
```

Não sei o que pode ser

Comment: Sabes qual é a linha que dá erro?

Comment: req.write(postData); Ao executar este comando.

Comment: Esse `req` é "de quem"? estás a usar o quê como servidor?

Comment: o `req` é o que uso para executar a função, estou usando Node.js

Comment: Estás a usar o servidor nativo do Node ou uma biblioteca como o Express?

Comment: Utilizo o método nativo do Node.

Comment: Ok, e esse `postData` é o quê? O `req.write` só aceita strings ou buffer.

Comment: Quando eu chamo esta função eu paço um corpo em json, o postData recebe este Json e inclui no corpo da minha requisição como buffer. `options.headers['Content-Length'] = Buffer.byteLength(postData);`

Comment: A documentação refere que ou string ou buffer: https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_write_chunk_encoding_callback Não podes mandar esse objeto como string? ou vais enviar um stream?

Comment: Pois é, tentei mandar como String e funcionou, único problema é que a Cielo não aceitou dessa forma. Pelo menos agora já descobri o motivo do erro, muito obrigado.

Comment: O ciel é software do lado do servidor certo? talvez precise de headers par autentificação?

Comment: Sim, vou ler a documentação da Cielo ver se consigo alguma resposta.